# Is it possible to get the actual object type if it is assigned to an interface type?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface ITransaction and Class1, Class2 all implements this interface. At runtime i assign a object of Class1 or Class2 to a reference of ITransaction.

`ITransaction itransaction = new Class1();` or

```
ITransaction itransaction = new Class2();
```

Is it possible to know the actual type that was assigned to the itransaction reference, may using reflection or something else?

Comment: Have you tried `typeof` or `.GetType`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `GetType()` on the interface instance to get the effective type.

(Note that this may not return what you expect for COM and remote interfaces of `MarshalByRefObject` instances, but that is a different topic.)

Comment: Thanks. :) i knew that method. I Thought i would only be able to use them for concrete class only. So, was it MarshalByRefObject?

Comment: If you have a remote interface instance you actually have a proxy object implementing the interface, and therefore using `GetType()` will not return the "original" object type on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
if (itransaction is Class2)
```